# What does this mean in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I was going through a codebase written in Coffescript, and I came across this statement:

`@$('.js-edit-feedback-section').addClass('hidden')`

If I'm not mistaken this translates to

`this.$('.js-edit-feedback-section').addClass('hidden')`

What's the advantage of doing this instead of using the jQuery selector directly like:

`$('.js-edit-feedback-section').addClass('hidden')`

Comment: there is no differencet betwen `this.$()`  and `$()`, if we are in the global context `window`

Comment: @albanx But this is not in the global context, this is inside a Coffescript class.

Comment: yes but it is going to be translated in pure javascript after compile

Comment: The difference is `this.$()`, being presumably a `Backbone.View`, gets scope to the view's elements only (e.g., similar to `@$el.find`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Backbone.View where Backbone.View.$ is a bit different than global jQuery.

> If jQuery is included on the page, each view has a $ function that runs queries scoped within the view's element. If you use this scoped jQuery function, you don't have to use model ids as part of your query to pull out specific elements in a list, and can rely much more on HTML class attributes. It's equivalent to running: view.$el.find(selector)

http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar